# Optimal my.cnf settings for MacBook Pro 15" i7 (localhost)

Tags: mysql, optimization, osx-snow-leopard, mac

What is the most recommended optimal my.cnf settings for the newest MacBook Pro 15" i7 with 4GB of RAM.

http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs.html

Only for local processing only. I want it to be full performance of speed as I use heavy data processing of MySQL locally.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl - GitHub](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl) to give recommendations on my.cnf changes. You'll need to run sample jobs to let tuner gather specs and make recommendations, And there's also [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) for monitoring.